# How to enable different SSL certificate for different location using Nginx?

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate, nginx-location

Suppose I have only ONE domain name "example.com". I want to enable SSL certificate using "A.crt" when visiting "https://example.com/api/A" and using "B.crt" when visiting "https://example.com/api/B". How can I achieve this with Nginx configuration? Thanks.

Comment: You can not - the `ssl_certificate` directive is valid only inside `http` or `server` context and is invalid inside `location`. Use subdomains instead of folders.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dedicated server block for each certificate, as follows:

```
server {
 listen 443 ssl;
 server_name apiA; ...
 ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/A-ss.crt;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/A-ss.key;
 ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/A.crt;
 ssl_verify_client on;
 ssl_verify_depth 2; ...
 location /api/A/ { ... }
 }

server {
 listen 443 ssl;
 server_name apiB; ...
 ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/B-ss.crt;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/B-ss.key;
 ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/B.crt;
 ssl_verify_client on;
 ssl_verify_depth 2;  ...
 location /api/B/ { ... }
 }
```

where each TLS certificate-key pair `*-ss.crt`, `*-ss.key` belongs to the subdomain it serves, as set in its "Common Name" field.

This solution gives independent TLS connections at the cost of using subdomains.
Send the request with URL pointing to the distinct host name, but redirect it to the common IP address using a proxy or /etc/hosts (or `--resolve` option in curl).